# What are strategies to write large and manageable proofs in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have gone through the Software Foundations series and have good understanding of Coq basics. But, proofs of anything non-trivial become too long and tedious.

What are strategies to write manageable large Coq proofs for someone familiar with basics?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid, and more than that, fundamental question. Doing a good answer thou will take quite a bit of time: it'll require examining the main large-scale works in Coq, along with the paper talking about large-scale formalization itself such as the ones coming from NICTA.

Answer (score 2):

This is an important question, but unfortunately too broad to have a satisfactory, overarching answer; in a sense, it is akin to wondering what the best strategy is for writing large, complex programs in your favorite programming language (but much worse, given that proof-assistant technology is not nearly as mature as conventional languages).

The most best advice that I can give is: don't try to brute force a proof.  If you think something is becoming too complex, stop, step back, and think if there is any change in the code that would simplify your life.  Maybe your definitions are not stated quite right; maybe you need some automation; or maybe the statement of your theorem is too complicated -- or, even worse, plainly false!  However, the only way to know how to proceed is with a concrete, specific example in hand that is giving you headaches.  Once you have one, we would be happy to help you.

Comment: In fact, I think the question could be rephrased as  "what are intereting large scale developments done in Coq", "what can we learn from them". I think that compiling such a list + a small summary could be great so people would have a shorther path towards complex examples.

Answer (score 1):

[*Certified Programming with Dependent Types*](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) (CPDT for short) is a good introduction often recommended along with or in place of *Software Foundations*.  It places a strong focus on short and automated proofs, and is a good introduction to learning tactic automation.